# How to find the sum: $1^{\frac{1}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}+3^{\frac{1}{3}}+ . . . +(50)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: summation

Can some one help me to find the sum of the following expression?

$$1^{\frac{1}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}+3^{\frac{1}{3}}+ . . .  +(50)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: I doubt there's a nice expression for that. Are you looking for something expressed in terms of special functions?

Comment: If not exact value at least approximate sum is fine to me.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+n%5E%281%2F3%29

Comment: You mean http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bi%5E%281%2F3%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C50%7D%5D&dataset=

Comment: Is the sum equal to integration of $x^{1/3}$ from 1 to 50.

Comment: The approximate sum is 139.7179005695.  You should really learn to program a computer, at least to the tiny extent needed to get the computer to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course a computer can evaluate it. You can also view this and similar sums in terms of a Riemann sum:
$$50^{1 \over 3}*50*\bigg[{1 \over 50} \bigg({1 \over 50}\bigg)^{1/3} + {1 \over 50}\bigg({2 \over 50}\bigg)^{1 \over 3} + ... + {1 \over 50}\bigg({50 \over 50}\bigg)^{1 \over 3}\bigg]$$
This is approximately
$$50^{1 \over 3}*50\int_0^1 x^{1 \over 3}\,dx$$
$$=50^{1 \over 3}*50*{3 \over 4}$$
$$= 138.1512...$$
This is reasonably close to the true value $139.7179...$

Answer (score 4):

Because $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, you can get bounds on the sum from

$$\int_0^{50}x^{1/3}dx\lt\sum_{k=1}^{50}k^{1/3}\lt\int_1^{51}x^{1/3}dx$$

Evaluating the integrals gives

$$138.151\lt\sum_{k=1}^{50}k^{1/3}\lt141.09744$$

You can get a better pair of bounds from

$$1+\int_1^{50}x^{1/3}dx\lt1+\sum_{k=2}^{50}k^{1/3}\lt1+\int_{2}^{51}x^{1/3}dx$$

which gives

$$138.4\lt\sum_{k=1}^{50}k^{1/3}\lt140.96$$

You can also try the approximation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{50}k^{1/3}\approx1+\int_{1.5}^{50.5}x^{1/3}dx\approx139.708$$

but it's hard to tell how many digits of that answer you can trust.

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed form for it, however it can be approximated by $\displaystyle\int_1^{50}\sqrt[3]x~dx=\bigg[\dfrac34x\sqrt[3]x\bigg]_1^{50}\approx$ $\approx137.4$

Comment: Could you briefly explain why this is an approximation?

Comment: (+1 for neat low-tech method.) Hey, that rings a bell for me! (See p. 5 of the .pdf file "cal_2W1_.pdf" posted [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6544585).)

Comment: You can get a somewhat better approximation if you don't subtract the $x = 1$ term, see my answer.

Comment: @user1729: ... Now to actually address your question: in general, with certain conditions of monotony and convergence in place, $\sum_a^bf(n)\approx\int_a^bf(x)dx$. _[edited ajf]_

Comment: @Lucian .... Could you perhaps give a reference? Will it be in a standard calculus text (if so, I cannot find it!). _[edited ajf]_

Comment: @user1729: Think about the very definition of a definite integral as a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). It should become pretty obvious.

Comment: @Lucian: Ah, okay, I understand. Each rectangle has area $x^3$ because it has base length $1$. I have learned something today - thanks :-)

Comment: @Lucian it would be more obvious with $a=1$ and $b=51$.

Comment: @user1729: Regarding your question *Could you perhaps give a reference?*, see the .pdf file I cited in an earlier comment here. It has labeled graphs, and all the basic details are included.

Answer (score 2):

You can bound the sum for any upper limit b.

$\frac{3 b^{4/3}}{4}<\sum _{n=1}^b \sqrt[3]{n}< \frac{3}{4} \
\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{1+b}+b \sqrt[3]{1+b}\right)$

Plugging in b = 50 you would get

$ 138.151<\sum _{n=1}^{50} \sqrt[3]{n}<141.097 $

Answer (score 1):

If you write :
$$S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n i^{1/3}$$
then notice that you can create the following difference equation :
$$S_n = S_{n-1} + n^{1/3}$$

This has no "nice" solution but only in terms of the Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions:

$$S_n = \zeta\biggl(-\frac13\biggr) - \zeta\biggl(-\frac13, n+1\biggr)$$

Using [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-HurwitzZeta%5B-1/3,%201%20%2b%2050%5D%20%2b%20Zeta%5B-1/3%5D), you find that :
$$S_{50} = \zeta\biggl(-\frac13\biggr) - \zeta\biggl(-\frac13, 51\biggr) \approx 140$$

Comment: Is there any simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) the sum 
$$ S = (1/2) 1^{1/3} + (2^{1/3} + 3^{1/3} + \cdots + 49^{1/3}) + (1/2) 50^{1/3} $$
can be approximated by the sum
$$ I = \int_1^{50} x^{1/3} \: dx $$
and therefore your sum can be approximated by
$$ I + (1/2) 1^{1/3} + (1/2) 50^{1/3} $$.
Doing the integral, this is
$$ (3/4) (50^{4/3} - 1^{4/3}) + (1/2) 1^{1/3} + (1/2) 50^{1/3} $$
or about 139.743.  The true value is about 139.720, so this is already quite accurate.

This is actually nothing but the [trapezoid rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), which works well because the function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ is so smooth.

To get a more accurate formula for this sum, you can use the asymptotic form of the Euler-Maclaurin formula (under "asymptotic expansion of sums" in the Wikipedia article); I leave the details to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [as much decimal expansion as you please at WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20n%5E%281/3%29%20from%20n%20=%200%20to%20n%20=%2050).

139.7179

Answer (score 0):

$$6+3 \sqrt[3]{2}+3\ 2^{2/3}+3 \sqrt[3]{3}+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3}+3^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{2} 3^{2/3}+3 \sqrt[3]{5}+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{5}+3^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{5}+5^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{2} 5^{2/3}+3 \sqrt[3]{6}+6^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{7}+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{7}+7^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{11}+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{11}+\sqrt[3]{13}+\sqrt[3]{14}+\sqrt[3]{15}+\sqrt[3]{17}+\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{21}+\sqrt[3]{22}+\sqrt[3]{23}+\sqrt[3]{26}+\sqrt[3]{29}+\sqrt[3]{30}+\sqrt[3]{31}+\sqrt[3]{33}+\sqrt[3]{34}+\sqrt[3]{35}+\sqrt[3]{37}+\sqrt[3]{38}+\sqrt[3]{39}+\sqrt[3]{41}+\sqrt[3]{42}+\sqrt[3]{43}+\sqrt[3]{46}+\sqrt[3]{47}$$

Comment: I hardly think this is helpful in any way. You could have used fewer keystrokes by simply replacing the "dots" in the OPs sum.

Comment: @amWhy I am actually the only one in this thread who has answered the OPs question. Everyone else has given decimal approximations, which are completely useless (unless you're a physicist). I have simplified the OPs expression as much as possible and given an exact form.

Comment: Your "answer" is more complicated than the original sum (and requires more computations), so, again I say, I hardly think this is an answer.

Comment: @amWhy How exactly is my answer more complicated? The OPs expression has 50 terms, my answer has only 43 terms.

Comment: Many terms with two factors, some of the form $a^{1/3}b^{2/3}$. As I said, the computational complexity of your un-answer greatly surpasses that of the OP's sum. I'm not going to argue with you anymore.

Comment: @Oliver I do agree that this is an answer, but it's epistemologically useless with the respect to the cognitive processes of most human beings. It's as much an answer as saying the given sum is $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{50}\left(n^{1/3}\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud Lucian and Zarrax both gave approximations, not exact answers.

Comment: @Oliver You're right. I didn't read them attentively enough. **Edit:** I've removed that part of my comment.